# Jquery onmouseover triggers on second event

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

I've created the following function in Jquery

```
function menuItem(x,i) {
var imgALT = $(x).text();   
$(x).mouseover(function()
{
    $(x).parent().parent().parent().children("img").attr("src", "menu/menu"+i+".jpg");
    $(x).parent().parent().parent().children("img").attr("alt", imgALT);
    $(x).parent().children("span").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
    $(x).css("color", "#CA0109");
});
};
```

And I trigger it using the following:

```
<span onmouseover="menuItem(this,'09-01')">月亮蝦餅 (2份)</span>
```

It works exactly as I intend it to, but only after I mouseover the span for the second time, not the first.  I assume this is perhaps a loading issue of some kind?  How should I go about ensuring it triggers on the first mouseover, as well as subsequent events?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're binding the event using jQuery only after you've hovered over the element and the inline `onmouseover` has fired.

Since it looks like that `onmouseover` event is critical to your application's structure, change your JavaScript to something like this:

```
function menuItem(x,i) {
    var $x = $(x);
    var imgALT = $x.text();

    $x.parent().parent().parent().children("img").attr("src", "menu/menu"+i+".jpg");
    $x.parent().parent().parent().children("img").attr("alt", imgALT);
    $x.parent().children("span").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
    $x.css("color", "#CA0109");
}
```

Ideally, I would use `data-` attributes:

**HTML**:

```
<span data-image="09-01">月亮蝦餅 (2份)</span>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span[data-image]').mouseover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $images = $this.parent().parent().parent().children("img");

        $images.attr("src", "menu/menu" + $this.data('image') + ".jpg");
        $images.attr("alt", $this.text());

        $this.siblings("span").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
        $this.css("color", "#CA0109");
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just going to add an answer with this method instead! Got there too quickly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').mouseover(function(){});
    });
```